# packages intallation error,,,npm command completed with exit code 1

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am using Angular 2 and the same problem is in every project where i use Angular 2, but all that projects normally build in another pc .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REOAX.png)

Comment: What's the npm command you run?

Comment: You're getting a 404 for angular material. Can you post your package.json please

Comment: I copy it from this link

Comment: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Yes, but that package.json doesn't have angular material, and yours does... It'll be much easier for us to help if you just edit your question with a copy of the text in that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have most probably **proxy settings** that prevent NPM to reach the registry.

This issue could happen if you have no internet connection (but I see in the screenshot that you have). In any case, if all build normally in another PC it is most probably related to your internet configuration, not to the NPM registry single point of failure.

Comment: can issue be connected with npm version or something like that?

Comment: error TS2415: Class 'WebSocketSubject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject<T>'

Comment: and when i add    "skipLibCheck": true this row in tsconfig.js file project build but what was connected with angular components hadn't load on page

Comment: after that can't restore packages